# How to avoid default return value when accessing a non-existent field with lenses?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I love Lens library and I love how it works, but sometimes it introduces so many problems, that I regret I ever started using it. Lets look at this simple example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Data = A { _x :: String, _y :: String }
          | B { _x :: String }

makeLenses ''Data

main = do
    let b = B "x"    
    print $ view y b
```

it outputs:

```
""
```

And now imagine - we've got a datatype and we refactor it - by changing some names. Instead of getting error (in runtime, like with normal accessors) that this name does not longer apply to particular data constructor, lenses use `mempty` from `Monoid` to create default object, so we get strange results instead of error. Debugging something like this is almost impossible.
Is there any way to fix this behaviour? I know there are some special operators to get the behaviour I want, but all "normal" looking functions from lenses are just horrible. Should I just override them with my custom module or is there any nicer method?

As a sidenote: I want to be able to read and set the arguments using lens syntax, but just remove the behaviour of automatic result creating when field is missing.

Comment: `Lens`es are mostly meant for pure product types. For sum types, there's `Prism`s. Perhaps, `makeLenses` should completely reject multi-constructor ADTs, but I suppose sometimes it's useful that it allows them. And it's pretty easy to remember that you need to watch out when using lenses with multi-constructor types, isn't it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ok, but can I read and write values when using `makePrisms`? I do not read each value as `Maybe` (using `preview`). I just want to read and set values like normal Haskell datatypes allow me to. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: @Wojciech Record types with more than one constructor are usually a bad idea, IMHO.

Comment: I suggest to change the title of the question to something like "How to avoid default return value when accessing a non-existent field with lenses?". As it currently stands the title is useless, it's just a rant without much content to be searched for. Since questions should be useful to many people for a long time it's appropriate to use title that can be easily searched for by others.

Comment: Vote very much not to close!  This is an interesting and important question.

Comment: @Bakuriu but it draws in the traffic. :)

Comment: @WillNess - Does not help future readers trying to answer their question though.

Comment: This is a reasonably clear question and does not deserve to be closed by any means! The only problem was a bad title, which I edited to try to actually describe the problem.

Comment: @Davorak correct. (a) I was joking; (b) ah! the title is already edited! good.

Comment: I think the problem is more related to records sum types, than lens. However, the fact that it doesn't return an error (as `_y b` will) is indeed controversial. However it's also sometime handy to not have to catch the error

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you just want to recover the exception behavior.  I vaguely recall that this is how view once worked. If so, I expect a reasonable choice was made with the change.

Normally I end up working with (^?) in the cases you are talking about:

```
> b ^? y
Nothing
```

If you want the exception behavior you can use `^?!`

```
> b ^?! y
"*** Exception: (^?!): empty Fold
```

I prefer to use `^?` to avoid partial functions and exceptions, similar to how it is commonly advised to stay away from `head`, `last`, `!!` and other partial functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I too have found it a bit odd that `view` works for `Traversal`s by concatenating the targets.  I think this is because of the instance `Monoid m => Applicative (Const m)`.  You can write your own `view` equivalent that doesn't have this behaviour by writing your own `Const` equivalent that doesn't have this instance.

Perhaps one workaround would be to provide a type signature for `y`, so know know exactly what it is.  If you had this then your "pathological" use of `view` wouldn't compile.

```
data Data = A { _x :: String, _y' :: String }
          | B { _x :: String }

makeLenses ''Data

y :: Lens' Data String
y = y'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by defining your own `view1` operator. It doesn't exist in the `lens` package, but it's easy to define locally.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Data = A { _x :: String, _y :: String }
          | B { _x :: String }

makeLenses ''Data

newtype Get a b = Get { unGet :: a }

instance Functor (Get a) where
  fmap _ (Get x) = Get x

view1 :: LensLike' (Get a) s a -> s -> a
view1 l = unGet . l Get

works :: Data -> String
works = view1 x

-- fails :: Data -> String
-- fails = view1 y

-- Bug.hs:23:15:
--     No instance for (Control.Applicative.Applicative (Get String))
--       arising from a use of ‘y’
```